# Semitic and Hebrew etymology

Tags: etymology, historical-linguistics, semitic-languages

Semitic has historically been used to describe ancient languages spanning from Oman to Morocco through Egypt and Somalia. Today, Antisemitic is different to it's etymology, it doesnt refer to berber and somali and arabic at all. Wouldnt it be more logical to say anti-hebrew or anti-zionist? Why is the word semitic used for that context?

Comment: *Antisemitismus* (in German, whence English *antisemitism*) was coined as a more scientifically-sounding term for *Judenhaß* (Jew hatred), although not exactly identical (according to some, the Aryan race was superior to the Semitic race as a whole, not just to the Hebrew people). For much of today's usages it would indeed be more logical to say anti-{Hebrew,Jewish,Zionist,...}, depending on the context. But, as so often, the meaning of this compound is not exactly what you would expect looking at its components. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antisemitism#Origin_and_usage for more.

Comment: it's not really relevant to the point of the question, but amazigh (berber) or somali have never been referred to as semitic either linguistically or ethno-racially. Linguistically they are afroasiatic, with somali belonging to the cushitic branch, and in terms of race were historically seen as hamitic whilst more modern ethno-cultural classifications line up with the linguistic classification (i.e. both being afroasiatic, with somali being cushitic specifically)

Comment: you are correct though that the term antisemitism uses "semitic" in a more narrow sense (as jewish). As keelan points out, this was a deliberate attempt to appeal to scientific theories of race at the time, but it is also an example of the etymological fallacy https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy

Comment: @Tristan. "Never" is a big word.

Answer (score 3):

To complete Keelan's great reference, AntiSemitic was a term coined in 1880's German academic exchanges debating racial topics.

etymologically, it is inaccurate: *From the outset the term "anti-Semitism" bore special racial connotations and meant specifically prejudice against Jews. The term is confusing, for in modern usage 'Semitic' designates a language group, not a race. In this sense, the term is a misnomer, since there are many speakers of Semitic languages (e.g. Arabs, Ethiopians, and Arameans) who are not the objects of antisemitic prejudices, while there are many Jews who do not speak Hebrew, a Semitic language. Though 'antisemitism' could be construed as prejudice against people who speak other Semitic languages, this is not how the term is commonly used.*

I felt I was imagining some incoherence. It must have gained popularity because of it's ease of pronunciation and and the hypnotic repetition of the syllable "ti"...  i.e. in the same way that cocacola became popular for reasons of rhyme.

Comment: The TI's in _antisemitism_ aren't pronounced the same in English. The first one is tense /i/ after a voiced nasal, and the second one is lax /ɪ/ after a voiceless stop.

Comment: Yes true. and some also call it ant-eye-semitism. You surely know how to recognize hypnotic rhythmic words like Cocacola, Tencent, TickTock, Samsung, BBC, verizon, Antisemitic, Ben-Nevis, BOris jOnsOn, Antisemitic is a very nice sounding word compared to AntiJewish, which is more difficult for the brain to memorise, to repeat and to implant subconsciously. I study subconscious linguistics, it's very prevalent in politicis, for example, what does EU sound like subconsciously? eeew? Nonlinear programing and subconcious influence of double meanings like EU?

Comment: Is [this](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/WomenMen&BristlyThings.pdf) what you would call subconscious linguistics?

Comment: @jlawler It's very a very well written document, and it's intellectually very dense, so it would benefit from conversion to crisp fonts using OCR, there are free versions of OCR and academic institutions have very performant ones where you can copy research papers and it is reformatted in fonts rather than a digital scan. I would prefer to read it fully in crisp B/W fonts. It's a very interesting topic. I feel it would be lighter using graphs and perhaps an infomercial video. I was thinking of another field of subconcious linguistics called NLP,

Comment: I'm curious about why many famous brand names rhyme, and why people can be programmed by hearing similar sounds, if you want to give someone a present, the "thing i would most like to HANDLE BAR none, you say i want X, like a nice car like a BM- or an X-box. it could Be aN X box” and they guy then sais "I want a red BMX". I think that Brexit happened because the EU sounds like EEW in midlands english, and people were subconciously influenced.

Comment: @aliential - jlawler is the author of that paper on BR-, so probably he had a reason to publish it as it is.

Comment: @aliential The pdf is printable in black and white. I'll think about the infomercial.

Comment: its blurry for my eyes. The fonts have fuzzy edges on my PC i mean, they strain my eyes a bit. Just being helpful by mentioning OCR technology. It was such an eye-strain to read that I converted it using OCR in an effort to read it, prior to posting that it was blurry for my eyes. I know Jlawler wrote it around 1982-1990 and it's for that reason that he should publish high quality formatting in 2020. It rained on my dad's books in st johns oxford one day. just saying, hes 80. if i have to read a small book, i can't be getting eye strain. https://ibb.co/S0bDhY5

Comment: If the first free OCR program i find online can accomplish that good a result, you can imaging that AABBYY or the besst rated OCR on google play will convert your 2002 quality digital scans to high quality 2020 formatting in the blink of an eye. I would have loved to read your text in a eye-safe way, so it's probably worth figuring out how to make your lifes work acceptably readable to a 2020 casual dude, i have 19/20 eyes but it's too gaussian-blurry. Plus your work will be searchable via google once it is numeriquement translitterated.